# Cannot pass tests when using webkitSpeechRecognition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

I am using google's api `webkitSpeechRecognition` and because this is a chrome browser only api, when I run tests on my application it fails because it cannot find the `webkitSpeechRecognition` variable. When I run the tests on chrome they pass fine, but when I run them in the terminal it fails because of this. I am trying to make a build for the application but this problem is not letting me do so.

Anyone has any experience in this? Or have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a question that belongs on this site.

Comment: Why not? This is a valid question

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple javascript test to see if feature is available and perform accordingly. Something like this:

```
 if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {  
     // run specific features
 }
```

You can also use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) to use browser-specific features conditionally. See also [W3C wiki](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way) about it.